# How to Logout from a ui5 app and get redirected to another ui5 app login?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, logout, sap-fiori

I have developed various UI5 apps and if i want to logout on one of them, all UI5 apps should be logout out.

For example. The first App is a menu. So I login in the first Menu-App. From this app there is a link to another app. Now i want to logout from this app and want to geht the redirect link to the menu-login.

I have the following code for logout of the second app (not the menu-app):

```
    handleLogout: function (oEvent) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/sap/.../logoff", 
      }).done(function (data) { 
        if (!document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")) {
          window.localStorage.clear()
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/sap/.../logoff", 
            username: '', 
            password: '',
            statusCode: {
              401: function () {
              }
            },
            error: function () {
            }
          });
        }
      });
      var myVar = setInterval(function (oEvent) {
        window.location.replace("/sap/...->link to the menu<-");
      }, 100);
    },
```

The result of this code is, that i get redirected to the menu-app and not to its login. I guess because there am still logged in.

Is there a chance or some sort of code where i can logout of all existing ui5-apps?
Has it something to do with cache-settings?

Comment: How is the login implemented? If it's SSO, the user will be logged in automatically once you redirect after logout...

Comment: it is the standard sap fiori login. It's SSO.

Comment: There is no standard. If it's SSO, what protocol? SAML, OAuth, Kerberos, etc?

Comment: to set the "standard" login for custom ui5 apps in SAP, you have to adjust the service-configuration (transaction sicf)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is related with your session mechanism. How to you manage user session? Are you using cookies or local storage?
For example you need to invalidate cookies in logout process for cookie option.

Check your ClearAuthenticationCache method, it is look like using local storage method.

Comment: I am using cookies not local storage... do you know how to invalidate cookies in logout process?

Comment: You can send new cookie with same name with expire date to before current day in service side. Also you can try to remove it from client side before redirect.

Comment: ok i found something: document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;'; i guess the "name" should be my cookie-name. i will give it a try

Comment: Note: Some browser preventing changing cookies on client side.

Comment: ok i can delete the cookies, but nevertheless, the logout is still not working (i am testen in chrome)

Comment: Please try with Chrome cookie manager extension look like EditThisCookie and delete with them. If not resolve your issue without cookies, may it is use local storage also. You can check and remove local saved data in chrome developer tool tab.

Comment: login cookies are usually secure cookies, they are no accessible from javacript. you need to call the "/whatevery/backend/logout"(depending of your backend)  to destroy you credentials.